# Ошибка при запуске Телеграм бота на Node.js через Proxy

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, proxy

Мой код

```
process.env["NTBA_FIX_319"] = 1
process.env['PROXY_SOCKS5_HOST'] = '79.106.133.123'
process.env['PROXY_SOCKS5_PORT'] = '1080'
process.env['TELEGRAM_API_TOKEN'] = 'token'

const TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api')
const Agent = require('socks5-https-client')

const bot = new TelegramBot(process.env.TELEGRAM_API_TOKEN, {
    polling: true,
    request: {
        agentClass: Agent,
        agentOptions: {
            socksHost: process.env.PROXY_SOCKS5_HOST,
            socksPort: parseInt(process.env.PROXY_SOCKS5_PORT),
        }
    }
})

bot.on('message', (msg) => {
    console.log(msg)
    bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, "Privet")
})
```

В консоли выходит

```
    ...\node_modules\request\request.js:698
    self.pool[poolKey] = new Agent(options)
                         ^

    TypeError: Agent is not a constructor
    at Request.getNewAgent (F:\Data\Documents\Code\Telegram\bibliotekar\node_modules\request\request.js:698:26)
    at Request.init (F:\Data\Documents\Code\Telegram\bibliotekar\node_modules\request\request.js:490:37)
    at Request.RP$initInterceptor [as init] (F:\Data\Documents\Code\Telegram\bibliotekar\node_modules\request-promise-core\configure\request2.js:45:29)
    at new Request (F:\Data\Documents\Code\Telegram\bibliotekar\node_modules\request\request.js:127:8)
    at request (F:\Data\Documents\Code\Telegram\bibliotekar\node_modules\request\index.js:53:10)
    at TelegramBot._request (F:\Data\Documents\Code\Telegram\bibliotekar\node_modules\node-telegram-bot-api\src\telegram.js:267:12)
    at TelegramBot.getUpdates (F:\Data\Documents\Code\Telegram\bibliotekar\node_modules\node-telegram-bot-api\src\telegram.js:566:17)
    at TelegramBotPolling._getUpdates (F:\Data\Documents\Code\Telegram\bibliotekar\node_modules\node-telegram-bot-api\src\telegramPolling.js:190:21)
    at TelegramBotPolling._polling (F:\Data\Documents\Code\Telegram\bibliotekar\node_modules\node-telegram-bot-api\src\telegramPolling.js:102:8)
    at TelegramBotPolling.start (F:\Data\Documents\Code\Telegram\bibliotekar\node_modules\node-telegram-bot-api\src\telegramPolling.js:48:17)
    at TelegramBot.startPolling (F:\Data\Documents\Code\Telegram\bibliotekar\node_modules\node-telegram-bot-api\src\telegram.js:387:26)
    at new TelegramBot (F:\Data\Documents\Code\Telegram\bibliotekar\node_modules\node-telegram-bot-api\src\telegram.js:201:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\Data\Documents\Code\Telegram\bibliotekar\index.js:9:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:279:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:752:3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Перечитайте текст ошибки внимательнее. А также документацию к [socks5-https-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socks5-https-client#using-with-request). Там ясно написано, что экспортировать агента нужно так:

```
var Agent = require('socks5-https-client/lib/Agent');
```

Comment: `error: [polling_error] {"code":"EFATAL","message":"EFATAL: Er
ror: connect ECONNREFUSED 95.110.227.6:50459"}`